# Set default handler for "unrecognized selector" exception

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, unrecognized-selector

In Objective-C, is there a way to set a default hander to avoid `unrecognizedselector` exception ? I want to make the `NSNULL` and `NSNumber` to response all the methods in `NSString`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle the "unrecognized selector" exception, we should override two methods:

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation;
- (NSMethodSignature*)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector;
```

In this case, if we want NSNull to perform the NSSString method if "unrecognized selector" exception occurred, we should do this:

```
@interface NSNull (InternalNullExtention)
@end



@implementation NSNull (InternalNullExtention)

- (NSMethodSignature*)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    NSMethodSignature* signature = [super methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    if (!signature) {
        signature = [@"" methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    }
    return signature;
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
    SEL aSelector = [anInvocation selector];

    if ([@"" respondsToSelector:aSelector])
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:@""];
    else
        [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:aSelector];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use categories to add methods to the `NSNull` and `NSNumber` classes.  Read about categories in [*The Objective-C Programming Language*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1).

You can implement `methodSignatureForSelector:` and `forwardInvocation:` to handle any message without explicitly defining all of the messages you want to handle.  Read about them in the [*NSObject Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is.  Look at the example for forwardInvocation: in the documentation for NSObject here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Basically you override forwardInvocation and that is called when an object does not have a method that matches some given selector.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed besides - (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation, I also need to implement the - (NSMethodSignature*)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector